# Update state when page changes in React Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I have

```
const Page = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { page: {} };
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    const pageId = this.props.params.pageId;
    socket.emit('get page', pageId, (page) => {
      this.setPage(page);
    });
  },
  setPage(page) {
    this.setState({
      page: page
    });
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.state.page._id}</h2>
        <p>{this.props.params.pageId}</p>
      </div>
    );
  },
});
```

but it seems `componentDidMount` works when I load the page, but if I click on links to other pages, it won't update the page.

In the `render` function, `this.props.params.pageId` is updated when I change page, but `this.state.page._id` is the same as it was when I loaded the page.

I have tried debugging with

```
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('TEST IF THIS METHOD IS FIRED');

    const pageId = this.props.params.pageId;
    socket.emit('get page', pageId, (page) => {
      this.setPage(page);
    });
  },
```

but the function is not fired when I click other pages. I have also tried with `onChange` instead of `componentDidMount`, but it also didn't work.

Comment: can you initialize the state in getInitializeState

Comment: if you do a `console.log(page)` in`setPage` function and click a link what is logged in console?

Answer (score 0):

You could use componentDidUpdate(prevProps)

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.params !== undefined && this.props.params !== undefined) {
        if (prevProps.params.pageId !== this.props.params.pageId) {
            const pageId = this.props.params.pageId;
            socket.emit('get page', pageId, (page) => {
                this.setPage(page);
            });
        }
    }
},
```